# Galaxy S4 restarting and freezing after root

Tags: root-access, reboot, system-freeze, samsung-touchwiz

I recently made the mistake of rooting my Galaxy S4, accompanied by a few more customizations.

Problems that occur:

- TouchWiz freezes. One way to unfreeze is to hold down the Home button to see recently opened apps and then go back, so that Touchwiz wakes up. The other way is to pull down the Notification bar and click Settings or anything else from there that'll send me to a different app so I can avoid it. If I don't do any of these within 5 seconds the freezing occurs, the device restarts.
- The device also restarts when the CPU is *suddenly* expected to work hard. For instance, within the first minute of a call, or when the screen is locked/unlocked, a couple seconds after opening a music file. This happens 3-5 times a day, depending on usage. The restart is not always preceded by a freeze, but often there's a freeze before the restart.

Recent changes that may be causing such behaviour:

- Rooting using AutoRoot by Chainfire.
- Giving [CPU Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antutu.CpuMasterFree&hl=tr) root permissions after SuperSU is installed.
- Installing busybox.
- Patching modded Google Play Store (involves patching Core.jar package)

What I did so far:

- Uninstall CPU Master.
- Delete cache and data of Touchwiz
- Remove busybox
- Remove all custom patches from core.jar
- Install the original Google Play Store and update to latest version

I don't think Touchwiz is causing the crashes because somethimes the phone restarts while an app is in use.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I removed the original Samsung ROM altogether and switched to Cyanogenmod. Thus I may not be able to upvote/tick the replies from then on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crashes are caused by Poweramp 2.0.9 build 529.

How I found out:

- The player was freezing at the beginning of songs every once in a while and uninstalling it solved the problem. No more restarts :)

Maybe the crashes are caused by Play Store via apps that are utilizing the modded licence check of Play Store (Poweramp is one of them). But I cannot be sure since I don't have any other app that requires licence control.

Just wanted to say that if anyone else is having the same issue with modded Play Store, removing your licence requiring app (be it Poweramp or sth else) may be your solution.

**EDIT:** False alarm. The restarts have started after a couple of days, and now more often than ever.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I've been having a similar problem, but without the modifications you mention. My process was to root, install SuperSU, Titanium Backup and then restore a bunch of apps.

The first time I got the problem, I thought I had restored some system apps or something, so I reverted to stock, and tried again, but being more careful to only restore apps and stuff like wifi access points. This suffered the same problem (but possibly less so).

I've gone back to stock again, and I'm going to try it to see whether I get similar behaviour without rooting. If all is well for a day or so, then I'll root, and see if anything changes. If it's still stable, I'll start using apps that utilise root and see what happens.

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one. Kick back here when you reroot..

Answer (score 0):

Use Titanium or any other app that can delete system Apps and then DELETE EVERYTHING RELATED TO KNOX (samsung protection crap).

The freeze is caused because Knox keeps trying to block SU access and somehow the system crashed and it reboots. I had the same problem and doing this completely stopped both the freezes and the reboots.

Of course, make sure to BACKUP everything before. From system to apps (use Titanium aswell).

Comment: Upgraded to CyanogenMod so the problem resolved itself. Thanks anyway for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Xposed Module- Samsung KitKat systemserver crash fix. It says it's for a different version but it has stopped every crash/reboot and I'm on the Verizon NG6 update.